# Error communicating with impalad: TSocket read 0 bytes

Tags: runtime-error, impala

when i interact with impala i randomly get the error:

Error communicating with impalad: TSocket read 0 bytes.

The error is almost always related to tables that are truncated and repopulated every day.
I've tried refreshing the tables, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks in advance.